# How to use StyledComponents theme inside of Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

Below I've created a style called Link. However the theme is inside of `this.props`. What is the way to get the theme out of props and passed into the `Link` styled component?

> ReferenceError: theme is not defined

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { withTheme } from 'styled-components';

export const Link = styled.p`
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;

  a {
    color: ${theme.apricot};  // <-- error
    cursor: pointer;

    :hover {
      color: ${theme.offWhite};   // <-- error
    }
  }
`;

class NomicsLink extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.theme);
    return (<Link>Powered by <a href="https://nomics.com/" target="blank">Nomics APIs.</a></Link>)
  }
}

export default withTheme(NomicsLink);
```

This console.log prints the following:

```
{ red: '#FF0000',
  black: '#393939',
  grey: '#3A3A3A',
  lightgrey: '#E1E1E1',
  offWhite: '#EDEDED',
  apricot: '#FEBE7E',
  margin: 0,
  padding: 0 }
```

Comment: All styled components automatically receive `theme` as a `prop` You can access it with `props.theme`

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings I tried `this.props.theme` and `props.theme` and got `referenceError: props is not defined`

Comment: `(props)=>props.theme.red` should work for you

Comment: Ah yes thanks that was what I was looking for :) like do post your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `styled-components` receive `theme` prop automatically.

You can access them inside the styled component with:

```
const Link = styled.a`
  color: ${props=>props.theme.apricot};
`;
```

More options on theming, see [docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming)